# How to do page caching when doing pagination/infinity scroll?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have large dataset to display in which the order is constantly changing (like SO, HN, Reddit). Since Rails does caching at the page and action level, what can I do if the action rendered like in the case needs to be different depending on pagination params?

A couple strategies I could think of:

1. Do just object caching in redis/memcached - but most of my time is being spent in rendering ; if I did this I'd ideally have to move the rendering into javascript as well
2. use eTags - but then the client still has to get the page once.
3. cache the entire rendered dataset, and put some logic into the controller to grab the page it needs. Use a sweeper to expire it.

How can I best do this "out of the box?" I want to introduce the minimum amount of complexity.

Comment: I usually use javascript templates for these goals.

Comment: thanks - that didn't really answer the question though - I was looking peoples' experiences with individual object caching options